# How do I print the image once I've stored it in a variable PHP

Tags: php, html, image

First of all, I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm trying to design a simple application to practice handling form elements. Basically, I upload an image, push submit, and then the image gets displayed in the web browser. The form works perfectly, but I'm having trouble displaying the image once I store it into a variable.

Does anybody know how to do this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HI</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action = "blah.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type = "file" name = "dope">
<input type = "submit" value = "Upload Images" name = "submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file is:

```
<?php

$image = $_FILES;
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: thing is that php is "temporary", if you store value to variable then value is stored only for this one session, once the code execution ends all values are flushed and do not exist anymore, if you need any value to persist you need to store it somewhere where they persist options are files, database, session and cookie. Session do expire so they are temporary too, also session and cookie are not designed to hold big data, so you should consider which one either file or database will work for you best

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the mime type from the upload and read it back to the browser:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . $_FILES['dope']['type']);
readfile($_FILES['dope']['tmp_name']);
```

This will send a header with the correct mime type so the browser knows how to handle it, if it's an image it'll be handled inline, if it's an application the browser will download it. [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) reads a file and sends it to directly to the buffer.

Be aware that if you want to store the file for future reads you will want to move it and store the location in a database or similar using [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), e.g.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dope']['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

Then you can serve the file over and over providing `$destination` contains the file path:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($destination));
readfile($destination);
```